# How to amend history commit message without overwriting PRs and changing the authors?

Tags: git, rebase, git-commit

I've googled the method to "amend history commit" by typing

```
git rebase -i c27f02e
```

, and then change the `pick` to `squash` or `reword`.

These operations can successfully

- amend the history commit messages and
- combine multiple history commits

---

In the certain repo, since there are commit histories that I merged from other contributors' PRs, like:

```
Merge pull request #80 from XXX/patch-1
```

Amending the commit histories will cause the following issues:

1. overwriting the above commit message and
2. the authors of the PRs I've merged will become both `ORIGNAL_AUTHOR & ME` from just `ORIGINAL_AUTHOR`

I don't want the above situations to happen.

I wonder if there's any way to amend the commit histories **without changing the above**.

I found something in [this article](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing#the-golden-rule-of-rebasing).

> But, there are two trade-offs for this pristine commit history: safety and traceability. If you don’t follow the Golden Rule of Rebasing, re-writing project history can be potentially catastrophic for your collaboration workflow. And, less importantly, **rebasing loses the context provided by a merge commit—you can’t see when upstream changes were incorporated into the feature**.

Thank you!